# Is there a 3D library for objective-c like papervision or away3D for actionscript

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, 3d

Is there a 3D library for objective-c  like papervision or away3D for actionscript?
To clarify, I'm writing the app in objective-c.

All I really need to do is contruct a 3D sphere programmically and attach raster images and buttons around the inside of the sphere.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cocos3d](http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/) is a nice, idiomatic Objective-C library for rendering 3D on iOS platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Most of the app will not be 3D. Only certain views called up dynamically. Do you know if I can add cocos3d views at will like I would a UIView? Or does the whole app have to be in Cocos3d?

Comment: @intomo: Yes, you can mix and match cocos3d with the rest of UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL would be the best way to do 3D I would imagine.

[OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793)